# How to create alert with redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, rest, alert, crud

Hi I want to create an success alert when a gossip was created and return on my home page or put's an danger alert when the validation fail

I've just succeeded to setup the error alert.

Here is my gossip controller :

```
class GossipsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @gossips = Gossip.all
  end

  def show
    @gossip = Gossip.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @error = false
  end

  def create
    @gossip = Gossip.new(title: params[:title], content: params[:content], user: User.find(182))

    if @gossip.save
      redirect_to root_path 
    else
      @error = true
      render "new"
    end
  end
end
```

And here it's my view of new :

```
<% if @error %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      <strong>Error</strong>
      <ul>
          <% @gossip.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
        </ul>
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
<% end %>   

<h2>Create your own gossip !</h2> <br><br>

<%= form_tag url_for(action: 'create'), method: "post" do %>

    <%= label_tag 'Title :' %> <br>
    <%= text_field_tag 'title'%> <br><br>

    <%= label_tag 'Content :' %> <br>
    <%= text_area_tag 'content'%> <br><br>

    <%= submit_tag "Create Gossip" %>
<% end %>
```

I've try to do same for the success alert but if i put a `@success = true` in the controller and `<% if @success %>` in the index view that don't work. I don't have any ideas.

Tell me if you need some part of my code.

I've tried with flash but that doesn't worked and whatever i want the same style with the error and success alert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create flash message partial app/views/layouts/_flash.html.erb
(please give filename with underscore since it partial)

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %> 
  <div class="alert alert-<%= key == "success" ? "success" : "danger"  %>">
    <%= value %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

add partial to your app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>
  ...
  <%= render 'layouts/flash' %> 
  <%= yield %>
</Body>
</html>
```

in your controller

```
def create
  @gossip = Gossip.new(title: params[:title], content: params[:content], user: User.find(182))

  if @gossip.save
    flash[:success] = 'success'
    redirect_to root_path 
  else
    flash[:danger] = @gossip.errors.full_messages[0]
    render "new"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't write in every form view instead of that you can just write common code to show the alerts related to success or error and then use that from any controllers :-

```
## app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

<html>
  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %> ## your header layout
    <div class="container">
      <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
        <div class="alert <%= flash_class(key) %>"><%= value.try(:html_safe) %></div>
      <% end %>
      <%= yield %>
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %> ## your footer layout
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Use helper to get correct bootstrap classes according to your requirement :-

```
module ApplicationHelper
    def flash_class(level)
    level = level.to_sym
    case level
        when :notice then "alert-info"
        when :success then "alert-success"
        when :error then "alert-danger"
        when :alert then "alert-warning"
    end
  end
end
```

And then use above code in any controller :-

```
if @gossip.save
  flash[:success] = "Your success custom message."
  redirect_to root_path 
else
  err_msg = ""
  flash.now[:error] = @gossip.errors.full_messages.map{|msg| err_msg << "#{msg} <br> "}
  render "new"
end
```

> **Note** :- Use flash when you are redirecting, and flash.now when you are rendering.

## edited content :-

Add `<br>` tag in error messages before showing and then on view page add `.html_safe` for showing every error in next line. This hack should be work and user will able to see all error messages related to object.

```
flash.now[:error] = @gossip.errors.full_messages.map{|msg| err_msg << "#{msg} <br> "}
```

In view

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
   <div class="alert <%= flash_class(key) %>"><%= value.try(:html_safe) %></div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I've succeeded for the flash success but how include `@gossips.errors.full.messages.each` etc... ? for the error way

Comment: @FFouquet42 I have just edited my answer. You can try this and it will work.